# Use php generated ids within jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am pulling my id's from a database with a foreach loop in a html file using

```
<div id="<?php print ($schedule['boxA']); ?>">
```

The question is how to use id's generated this way in a jQuery script?

```
 <script> 
 jQuery('I NEED TO INPUT ID HERE').datetimepicker({
     datepicker:false,
     format:'H:i',
     step: 15,
 });

</script>
```

Comment: `$('#IDOFDIV')` Replace IDOFDIV with the ID of the div..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (and do) use a different pattern. You don't need to use the ID to reference an element with jQuery, so you can add a datetimepicker widget more generically by using the class selector.

HTML (inside `foreach` loop):

```
<div class="timepicker" id="<?php echo $schedule['boxA']; ?>">
```

JavaScript (only once):

```
<script> 
jQuery('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'H:i',
    step: 15,
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the generated id's the same way that you always do in jQuery.

```
jQuery('#generated_id') // replace 'generated_id' with the id supplied by PHP
```

If you are wanting to echo the id's you could do something like this when the page is being rendered -

```
jQuery("#<?php echo $schedule['boxA']; ?>").datetimepicker({
```

Comment: <script> 
    
       jQuery('#<?php print ($schedule['boxA']); ?>').datetimepicker({
       datepicker:false,
       format:'H:i',
       step: 15,
       });
       
        </script> 
Puting php directly in to the script is not working

Comment: Are you trying to echo jQuery to your page?

Comment: i am trying to generate jquery time pickers for various inputs and the inputs id's are stored in a database

Comment: So you're using those database values to output a page complete with jQuery, right?

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the output? Doesn't echoing the id work?

Comment: echoing tha ids in the html works. But i think that the way i am trying to input them in the script is not working

Comment: Can you share the PHP where you're outputting the jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea.

I would suggest something like:

```
<div id="boxA" data-id="<?=$schedule['boxA']?>">
```

Or similar. The ID should be constant and known - that's what makes it an IDentifier. `data-id` can then be used to hold the server's ID reference to the thing in question.

Comment: if I use data id, what is the way to input the data-id in the jquery script? should i alter the script?

Comment: `$("#boxA").data("id")` will retrieve the ID.